# Subscribe to Queue for a set length of time

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am using .Net Core 2.1 and I have a Web Api project that subscribes to a queue using a MessageReceiver.

What I want is for this subscriber to stay "alive" for x minutes.
Now I must admit that I actually thought that the Timeout actually worked this way but I don't think that is the case.  This is what I have so far

```
     var reciever = new MessageReceiver(connectionString, queueName);
     Message message = await reciever.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

     if (message != null)
     { 
          // process
     }
```

So this is what I am expecting, any messages that hit the queue while this piece of code is running, will be processed.

What I am seeing is that it seems to wait for the timeout to expire before "reading" the message from the queue.
Maybe I have misunderstood how the subscriber should work, but what I would like is for the subscriber to just subscribe to the queue for the timeout time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReceiveAsync(waitTime)` is a one time receive until one of the following conditions is fullfilled:

1. There are messages to be recieved
2. `waitTime` has elapsed

If you want to tie receive operation to a certain period of time, you would either have a loop / message pump for the duration you're interested in that receives message. Or, you could [register a message handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.subscriptionclient.registermessagehandler?view=azure-dotnet) in order not to build your own message pump. The drawback of the second option is that to stop receiving you'd need to close the receiving client. Where with the first option, you don't need to close it therefore keeping connection alive.

Potential solution closed connection would be crating your client with `ServiceBusConnection` rather than a connection string. That way, when a client is closed, connection is still kept alive.

Comment: So it is a waitTime, ah OK.  The documentation wasn't that clear. When you say "There are messages to be received" I'm guessing that they would only be read after the waitTime has expired, not instantly.  Which would marry up with what I am seeing. The solution would be some sort of timer loop with the register message handler

Comment: Solution could be one of the options I've suggested. BTW, messages are received the moment they are available, not _after_ `waitTime` elapses. So if there's a message sitting in the queue, it will be received immediately.